# Cannot display Wordpress version from WP website?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display my Wordpress version on an external website, the below code used to work, however it's not anymore.

I cannot

```
<?
//get the WordPress homepage 
$wp_homepage=file_get_contents('http://wordpress.org'); 

//find start point of the version 
$version_start=strpos($wp_homepage,'Download&nbsp;WordPress&nbsp;');
if($version_start===false) 
{ 
    die('4.1.1'); 
} 
//get rid of the download WordPress part 
$version_start+=29; 

//find end point of version 
$version_end=strpos($wp_homepage,'</a>',$version_start); 

//find the version stated 
$wp_version=substr($wp_homepage,$version_start,$version_end-$version_start); 
?>
```

I don't understand why it's not working anymore.

Maybe there is a better way as well?

Thanks

Edit: nevermind seemed the code was outdated it only needed

Solved.

Comment: If you have fixed it then please share your answer so that people who are looking for a similar answer can get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**just use below code for check wp version**

```
<?php get_bloginfo('version'); ?>
```

Comment: That probably only works from within a Wordpress website. I clearly mentioned pulling the WP version from an external website? Nevermind fixed it already.